# Implement joomla 3.2 component admin site

Tags: joomla

I am implementing a component admin site, and i want to achieve the following two functions.

one, every entry in the list has a status tool bar like following picture.
[image]

two, the joomla tool bar when click on it, for example, the NEW button, it will lead to the create new page.

[image]

Comment: i add the JToolbar code in the respecting file, and now it shows correctly. but i have no clue of how to implement the status toolbar, or any name you call it..

Comment: Take a look at how the core Joomla components do this. Would be a good place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a component based on Joomla standards all these options like Basic Toolbar, Sort options, Paging options etc are available.

So you have to create component based on your Joomla version.

check this [link](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aComponent_Development#Intro_to_Component_Development) it have all details about component development,

We can't answer here the all the workflow, you will get all documentation there also it provides a demo component, download that and modify with your requirement,learn the structure.

You can download the sample hello world Component from [here]

Comment: What is the name of this status tool bar? Where can i find the documentation of implementing it?

Comment: and for the toolbar, the code is like this                                                       **JToolbarHelper::publish('contacts.publish', 'JTOOLBAR_PUBLISH', true);**,   what is the task contacts.publish? where to build this task, in the model?

Comment: did you download the sample component from Joomla sites ? It have all the details, JToolbarHelper::publish(..) needs to placed inside your view.html.php file based on add/edit. contacts.publish means controller file name contact.php and inside that a function publish if you failed to find such a function inside that controller it may load Joomla native library. Controller calls corresponding model functions M-V-C

Comment: where to download the sample component? i cannot find it on the page you provided..

Comment: check this http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Basic_backend and this too http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/11394/58397/com_helloworld-1.6-part07.zip

Comment: hi, i have already developed a front end site component, but in the page it does not teach how to implement the "status" icon and how to make it function. Could you please give me some information about that?

Comment: check all parts http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_09 The documentation have next at last